# Einstein Bot - Whatsapp to Specific agent

Tags: einstein, einstein-bots

I'm creating the Einstein Bot and I need to make a conversation where the Bot will take someone's information (till here, I'm ok), find if this person has a Opportunity and in case it has, I need to transfer to this specific Agent.
Is it possible? If so... how? Because I saw Queue and Bot transfer, not to specific Agents.

Answer (score 0):

Have you found a solution?
Also, have you managed to transfer whatsapp chat to a queue after defining the queue?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/170170)